# Adding records from Excel Sheet into Oracle database on clicking a button on some website

Tags: php, sql, database, excel, oracle

I want to add records from Excel Sheet into Oracle database on clicking a button on some website.

For example, I have a php page where a button to add bulk records.

On clicking the button an excel file is asked from which the records are to be added in the oracle database.

On choosing the file the records are added into oracle database directly.

Comment: Well, Sounds like a plan. What you have tried so far to achieve it ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen i am trying to write some oci commands. Being new to oci commands and oracle database, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen i know how to enter from inside toad but want to add with help of a button on webpage

Comment: I really don't know anything about the oci commands or oracle database. But as you say you already know how to the (action) enter from inside toad. Why not you fire the action while the trigger is called (button is pressed) ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen i dont know how to control toad functionalities via some command in php script

Comment: It can be simply done by firing it by simple jquery-ajax call. If you want me to help in it, I shall do it :)

Comment: Is the excel in CSV format? If so, it should be straight forward case of reading each record and then INSET into the table. Assuming you have got the Oracle-PHP setup completed.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen can you help please. It would be great if you can solve this problem. Please explain the steps you want to me to do via jquery-ajax

Comment: @RockerRocky Sure, Writing answer for you :)

Comment: @TenG how should i do by your approach. I have PHP and Oracle installed with Toad also installed. Now how should i do according to steps mentioned by you

Comment: Okay, I will list you the steps you have to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

Note : As i mentioned in comments i don't know about Toad or Oracle, But i can help you with the Common/General practice to achieve it.

**Short Summary :**

1. Trigger
2. Do Action for Trigger
3. Show the Result

**Actual Workaround :**

The Best Way i would always recommend is to use some button/image with some id that will fire your Trigger. You can have it by

**Step 1 :**

Make sure you Load it once the document is ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Your code here
});
```

**Step 2 :**

Create and Track your Trigger

Have a button with some id like

```
<button id="MyButton">Click</button>
```

And Track it by

```
$("#MyButton").click(function(){
console.log("The Trigger is Fired");
});
```

**Step 3 :**

Fire the Event

Make your Work here, i.e., In the place where i did the console.log you can do your operation

As your function is something related with external files, you can made it possible by passing parameters in curl call or file_get_contents

**Method 1 : Curl**

Here's a short example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

You have your own address for your purpose and pass parameters that you wish to have.

**Method 2 : File Get Content**

Here's my own example which i derived right now for you

This is about finding the duration between two points in Google Map

```
$RequestUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$MyLat.",".$MyLong."&destinations=".$TargetLat.','.$TargetLong;
$GoogleApiResult = file_get_contents($RequestUrl);
$GoogleApiResultDecoded = json_decode($GoogleApiResult);
```

And you can get the result by

```
 $GoogleApiResultDecoded->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration->text
```

[Note : This is just a example which deals with external file, you can customize it for your need]

**Step 4 :**

Show your Result

Once the operation is done, you shall show the output of the work that you performed in the success function of the action

First you need to define some div with any id

```
<div id="YourResult"></div>
```

i.e.,

```
$.ajax({
   url: "yourexternalurlwhereyoudealwithoracle.php/someextension",
    type: "POST", // or GET your Prefer
    data: yourdata,
    async: false,
    success: function (msg) 
    {
     console.log('youractionisdone');
     $("#YourResult").html("Successfully Done !");
    },
});
```

Now, You will get the output "Succesfully Done !" in the Div you defined. You can pass some real if you wish in that case you shall replace the text by

```
$("#YourResult").html(data);
```

**Now you're done !!**

Comment: where is the database part of adding records. And i want the a file is asked to be uploaded which further can be uploaded in database

Comment: I have given you the logic, May i see the code that you have to achieve the database part ?

Comment: Tell me one thing.

What i have to write in the curl_init("What to write here")

Also in fopen("path of file") should file be in folder where my localhost is

Comment: And can you explain the Get Content method as i haven't used JSON's.

Basically i have to upload a file and send records into database

Comment: Both curl and get content is nothing but requesting the external file's support which might contain the process you wish to do - It can have some db part

Comment: So after i do curl_setopt and curl_exec what is happening with the file that is being opened. How to read its content and insert into database. How to get those records inside the file i opened.

Comment: both will just run/execute the file. You can read its content by outputting from it !